# How to bounce ball of moving paddle

Tags: java, bluej

Ok so I'm having some difficulty with a game I have been trying to program on BlueJ. So far I have a ball bouncing around, and a paddle that I can move around with my mouse. I'm trying to get the ball to bounce off my paddle basically where ever I move it.

I have three classes, I know its long but i could really use some help.

```
public class MAIN {

    public void begin(){
        Paddle = new Paddle(140,400,100,canvas);
        ball = new Ball (180,50,canvas, Paddle)//ball can recognize paddle
    }

    public void onMousemove (Location p){
        Paddle.move(p);
    }
}

public class Paddle {

    public Paddle (int x, int y, int s, DrawingCanvas c){
        ((JDrawingCanvas)c).setBackground(Color.green);
        paddle = new FilledRect(x,y,s,10,c);
    }
    public void move (Location p){
        paddle.moveTo(p.getX(),p.getY());
    } //paddle, and to move paddle
}

public class Ball {

    Drawing Canvas myCanvas;
    FilledRect paddle;
    FilledOval ball;
    int dx = 3, dy = 5;

    public Ball (int x, int y, int s, DrawingCanvas c, Paddle paddle){
        myCanvas = c
        ((JDrawingCanvas)c).setBackground(Color.green);
        ball = new FilledOval (x,y,s,s,c);
        pad = paddle;

        start();
    }

    public void run () //bounces the ball around
    {
        while(true){
            if(ball.getX() <0 ||ball.getX() > myCanvas.getWidth()){
            dx = dx;
        }
        if(ball.getY() <0 ||ball.getY() > myCanvas.getWidth()){
            dy = dy;
        }
        move5();
        pause(20); 
    }

    public Rectangle getRectangle(){
        return new Rectangle ((int)paddle.getX(), paddle.getY(), 
        paddle.getWidth(), paddle.getHeight();
    }

    public boolean collision (Ball p){
        return getRectangle().intersects(p.getRectangle());
    }

    public void move5(){
        ball.move(dx,dy)
    }

    public void collide(){
        dx= -dx
        dy=-dy
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to use the same collision detection which is used for the sides of the screen to detect whether the ball is touching the paddle.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a hitbox for your ball, check in each frame if its overlaping with to upperor lower boundary of your paddle. if yes, invert y velocity of the ball. Samebfor the x axis.

The ball is colliding with a line if the ball's coordinate (lets say on the y axis) minus its radius is smaller than the y coordinate of the line and the ball's y coordinate plus its radius is bigger than the limne's y coordinate and the ball's x coordinate +- its radius is smaller/bigger than the line's end point's x coordinates. so basically you check if the ball is between the ends of the line and not further away from the line than its own radius. if thats the case the ball collided with a boundary of your paddle.